# Permission Denied error in Yii

Tags: php, yii, runtime-error, file-permissions

I am working on a blog system in which I have installed an extension in named CAdvancedArBehavior.php in my extensions directory.

Now after calling it, I keep getting this error :

```
require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sanblog/protected/extensions/CAdvancedArBehavior.php) [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Now I know that this may be because, I must not have given proper rights to my folders, however I even did a :

```
chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sanblog/
```

I have reverified that all the folders have been given all the folder permissions, however I am still getting the error. I have checked out the question everywhere and everywhere it's just said that this is due to the folder permissions, however I am sure that my permissions are correct.

Just where am I going wrong?

Regards,

Comment: PHP shows same error when trying to `require` folder instead of file, could it be possible that you have **folder** `CAdvancedArBehavior.php`?

Comment: No it is a file. Am 100% sure of that. I guess i ll have to leave this extension.

Comment: did you chmod with the appropriate privileges (likely root or the folders owner) ?